# Regex to remove a non-alphanumeric character at the end of a string which also appears else where in the string

Tags: c#

I am not good at Regex and need help creating expression to remove the '/' character at the end of a pageUrl: https://qa.test.celtic.com/
I have tried a few expressions but each time it either removes all the '/' characters or none. The string may change but the last '/' will always be present.
Have used [a-zA-Z:/.]$ but it returns the '/' character only.
I could the find the character in the string as a substring and then replace in the string using code but would rather find a regex expression that just took the string without the trailing character.

Answer (score 7):

why don't you use the `TrimEnd()` method to remove a specific character at the end of a string?

```
string url = @"https://qa.test.celtic.com/";
string result = url.TrimEnd('/');
```

Comment: Thanks very much fubo, this should work and I will redesign how I was attempting to condition the string. But if there is a regex expression that would do the same without code then would be glade to know.

Comment: @Eamo:- Why to use a sword when things can be done using a needle? You can get the string without using the regex. Using regex would not be a good idea in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [@fubo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35916827/791010), and would use something more appropriate for the job than Regular Expressions.

That said, if you *really* want to use a regex, you simply look for a `/` at the end of the string, which is designated in regex as `$`:

```
Regex.Replace("https://qa.test.celtic.com/", "/$", "")
```

Or if your question is really "how do match the value without the /", then you need a capturing group that finds everything apart from the `/` at end end:

```
Regex.Match("https://qa.test.celtic.com/","(?<host>.*)/$").Groups["host"].Value
```

Answer (score 0):

> The string may change but the last '/' will always be present.

You can try like this:

```
String res = url.Substring(0,url.Length -1);
```

You can also put a check like

```
if ( url!=null && url.EndsWith('/') )
{
    String res = url.Substring(0,url.Length -1);
}
```